# What happened with TensorFlow Lite documentation for the Interpreter class

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tflite

I started working on a project using TensorFlow Lite in C++. I have often looked up information about the API in the [official reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/cc). Almost all of the methods are used were listed in the `Interpreter` class. However, a few days ago I noticed, that the `Interpreter` class has been completely removed from the documentation. Other classes are still listed there.

When searching for methods only present in the C++ API like [typed_input_tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/s/results?q=typed_input_tensor), search results show class reference for `tflite::Interpreter``, but only return 404 when followed. Does anyone have any idea is the class reference moved to a different place, or removed alltogether?

Comment: The link you shared works for me. Are you sure it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Ah, now it works for me as well. I guess it was just a temporary bug or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out it was just a temporary bug, everything works now, thanks [Karim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10952155/karim-nosseir) for pointing it out.